# Flutter how to send a feedback on input error

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

##### Send a feedback on input error

Im working on a flutter i need a label to report errors on login phase. I can't find anything related to text label on flutter. Everytime i search for it i get TextField and i don't need it.

I would like to use a Label and change the message based on my java code response.
This is the code i used for the label.

```dart
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 100,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  '$error',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      fontSize: 30),
                )),
```

Change the value of error should automaticaly change the label message?

Do you guys have any good website were i can learn more about flutter?

##### Issue solved by using SnackBar

The problem was solved by using a SnackBar. Flutter provides this object which is ideal for real-time feedback.

```dart
    void showSnackBAR(String text, BuildContext context, Color bgColor, Color textColor){
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        text, 
        style: TextStyle(
          color: textColor,
          fontSize: 15
        ),
      ),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      ));
  }
```

Comment: Do you want stateful widget? when java code response, u change state and label change, too.

Comment: How are you getting response from java code? If you are using methodChannel, you can use setState and if you are using EventChannel, you can use StreamBuilder.

Comment: @Rahul im using a method channel  to make dart and java comunicate. But seems that im not able to send the response and make update the ui also.

Comment: No worries. Once you get response from your method channel, try printing it (or use debug breakpoint) to see if you are getting expected response. Once that's done, you can use setState (for that you will have to use StatefulWidget) to assign value to your `error` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SetState() {} state management method to achieve this..
you can initially give some values inside Text Widget and once you get response from backend you can call SetState(){} in your method to change your previous text value and overwrite with new value.

SetState is used for reload your UI... commonly used for state management...

My Suggested one for you given below :

Instead of label you can give toast messages for your errors and success messages.

Implementation :

Dependency:

```
fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
```

Code Implementation :

```
 void showSuccessToast(String message) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: message,
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
    timeInSecForIosWeb: 4,
    textColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
    webPosition: "center",
    webBgColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #5aff15, #5aff15)",
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(90,255,21,1),
  );
}

void showFailureToast(String message) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: message,
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
    timeInSecForIosWeb: 4,
    textColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
    webPosition: "center",
    webBgColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #dc1c13)",
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(220,28,19,1),
  );
}
```

you can declare above two methods in a individual dart file and just call it in your project where ever you want and pass your message in method params

Comment: Thanks for idea in meanwhile i find out about SnackBar that can make me show errors with a better ui. The problem now is that seems that my await its not getting any responses and get stuck. Im duing  String er = (await platform.invokeListMethod("login", args)) as String; to get a simple string sended with result.success("This is a test");

Comment: yes snack bar too do the same thing...you can write the snack bar Widget as a common file and call it where ever you want in your project. because it will minimize your lines of codes.

Comment: Update:
Problem solved, the waiting error was caused by type error.

In fact I was passing an integer indicating the type error but handling it as a string.

( final int r = await platform.invokeMethod('login', args); )